# How to handle disabled layers in Multilayer EXR?

Tags: file-format, render-layers, .exr

I prefer exporting frames in *Multilayer EXR* with turned off *Compositor* to save some RAM. When scene involves disabling render layers, *Multi EXR* just throws them out.

Here you can see, that layer **"2"** is unchecked on second frame, and *Image node* provides next available layer, which is **Combined**.

[image]

This behaviour forces me to add *Switch* nodes drived in according with renderlayers to replace incorrect layers with empty value.

What can I do to make it work without additional steps?